# DeepImageFeaturizer returing error cannot import name ResNet50 from keras.applications in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, image-processing, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, google-colaboratory

I am trying to.implement image classification for.extracting features from images I am using DeepImageFeaturizer and using Inceptionv3 model
But the from sparkdl  import DeepImageFeaturizer is returning error
Import error: cannot import name ResNet50 from Keras.applications in pyspark colab.

Comment: Hey, any update on this?

Answer (score 1):

I think the error is related to the versions. I don't recommend it but you can try this :

Open this file :

**/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sparkdl/transformers/keras_applications.py**

instead of

`from keras.applications import resnet50`

to

`from tensorflow.keras.applications import resnet50`

Comment: You're a Lifesaver!  Raised an issue in the repo to take a look into this